# Monitor individual device traffic on Cisco RV042

Tags: cisco, bandwidth, monitoring

I am able to monitor Total Traffic consumption on the Cisco RV042 router using SNMP and PRTG.

I want to be able to monitor traffic used by each device on my net

Comment: If you have switch that supports SNMP, you can then create interface sesnsors in PRTG for switch ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that will do this is called Netflow (IPFIX).  Unfortunately, this router model does not offer it.  You could upgrade to a bigger router, or install a separate Netflow sensor.